# Ayuda con el manejo de un cierre de una session PHP

Tags: php, session, php7

Chicos tengo el siguiente caso:

Para iniciar sesion en PHP hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('private');
session_start();
```

y para cerrar la session hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['user']);
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
}
```

El boton cerrar sesion lo hago con un link a `?logout=1`

Pero me ocurre que si abro la session con el **usuario A** y salgo de dicha session y entro con la session del **usuario B** el navegador queda cargado con datos del **usuario A** y de hecho me muestra dichos datos hasta que hago un F5 en el navegador y actualiza y carga los datos del **usuario B**
Existe una forma en las pocas lineas que he presentado de destruir totalmente los datos (cookies, cache, etc etc) del usuario de la session anterior.

Comment: Con qué navegador? IE tiene el mal hábito de cachear páginas; en tal caso tendrías que añadir un parámetro aleatorio en la URL.

Answer (score 0):

es porque queda grabada en una coockie las variables, por ello debes de eliminarlo también.
Modifica tu destroy de session y agregarle la opción de suprimir dicho coockie.
si podrías revisar en las herramientas de desarrollador -> Almacenamiento. Encontraras que cada vez que realices una sesion este crea la cookie, por ello debes de destruirlo. para mayor seguridad.

## Destruir sesión

```
    function logout() {     
    unset($_SESSION);     
    $datos_cookie = session_get_cookie_params();     
    setcookie(session_name(), NULL, time()-999999, $datos_cookie["path"], 
    $datos_cookie["domain"], 
    $datos_cookie["secure"],               
    $datos_cookie["httponly"]);     
     // DIRECCIONA A TU PAGINA
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Sigue comportándose igual..!!

Comment: añade mas información si agregaste la opcion de eliminar la cookie

Comment: Con la herramienta de desarrollador me indica que se crea un galleta PHPSESSID y que expira 1969-12-31T23:59:59.000Z